# scrape text from slideshare slides (for multiple presentations)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Is there any method/package/framework to scrape text from slides on slideshare? The only method I could think of was to download slides as pdf and then run an OCR tool to extract text. I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this ? Ideally I would want to do this for multiple presentations and I am looking for a way to automate this process.

`EDIT : Adding example`

An example would be that say this slide has many elements. But below the comments we can get only the title of the slide. I was hoping that we can scrape the entire text off this slide.

[This is what is shown below the comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw4p4.png)

[This is the entire slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eO7g.png)

Comment: On Slideshare, the contents of the slides are also written below the comment section.

Comment: @xyres couldn't find it here https://www.slideshare.net/kleinerperkins/internet-trends-2017-report/2-KP_INTERNET_TRENDS_2017_PAGE . Could you please share an example?

Comment: @xyres I looked it up and observed that the entire data is not available below the comments.